# Maximum distance travelled by a body thrown up in air resistance if the air resistance is linearly dependant on its velocity?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

> Find maximum distance travelled by a body thrown up in air resistance if the air resistance is linearly dependant on its velocity. The mass of object $m$ is given and so is the relation $F_{\text{resistance}} = kv$. Assume a constant $g$.

This is what I have done till now:

$$F_{\text{resistance}} = kv$$ $$ F_{\text{gravity}} = mg$$
$$F = mg - kv$$
$$m \frac{dv}{dt} = mg - kv$$
$$\frac{{\rm d}v}{g-\frac{kv}{m}} = {\rm d}t$$
Integrating both sides
$$-\frac{m}{k}\cdot \log\left(g-\frac{kv}{m}\right) = t + c$$
which simplifies to:

$$v(t) = \frac{mg}{k} - Ce^{\frac{-kt}{m}}$$

Given condition $v(0) = u$ so $C = \frac{mg}{k} - u$ and

$$v(t) = \frac{mg}{k} - \left(\frac{mg}{k} - u\right)e^{\frac{-kt}{m}}$$

Let max height be $x$ and time taken to reach this height be $T$.
Since at the top, $v(T) = 0$,

therefore,

$$\frac{mg}{k} = \left(\frac{mg}{k} -u\right)e^{-\frac{kT}{m}}$$
or $$\log(mg/k)= \log(mg/k -u) - kT/m$$
$$kT/m = \log((mg -ku)/mg)$$
$$T = (m/k)\log(1 - ku/mg)$$

I need to prove that if $ku/mg <1$

$$T = u/g[1- (1/2)(ku/mg) + 1/3(ku/mg)^2 + \ldots]$$
and 
$$X = u^2/2g[1 - (2/3)(ku/mg) + 1/2(ku/mg)^2 + \ldots]$$

I don't know what to do now. I tried integrating $v(t)$ from $0$ to $T$ to get $X$ but thats such a complicated form and nothing similar to the required equation. All help is greatly Appreciated!

Comment: You are right that the height $X$ is found by integrating $v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$ from $0$ to $T$ giving us $X = \int_0^T v(t){\rm d}t$. Once you have done this then rewrite the expressions in terms of $y = \frac{ku}{mg}$ and try to series expand the expressions you find. The Taylor series $\log(1 + x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \ldots$ valid for $|x| < 1$ will be useful.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to properly typeset math on this site using mathjax.

Comment: That helped me get the expression for T, but I'm stuck on the one with x. When integrated, x comes out to to this expression "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+mg%2Fk+-+(mg%2Fk+-+u)e%5E(-kx%2Fm)+from+0+to+T"

While the first term simplifies nothing else does :/

Comment: Well first of all you entered it wrongly into Wolfram. Secondly it does simplify. Anyway you should do it by hand, it's a very simple integral on the form $\int [b + b e^{-cx}]\,{\rm d}x$. And the subsequenct algebra is not that complicated, it just requires you do do the effort and be careful in the derivation.

Comment: Another problem with your derivation is that you are not being very careful with the signs. In your first expressions you have $e^{+\frac{kt}{mg}}$ while later you have $e^{-\frac{kt}{mg}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems I was just messing up the signs, got the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Take upward as positve

\begin{align*}
  m\frac{dv}{dt} &= -mg-kv \\
  \frac{dv}{v+\frac{mg}{k}} &= -\frac{k}{m} \, dt \\
  \ln \left( v+\frac{mg}{k} \right)&=-\frac{kt}{m}+C \\
  v &= \left( u+\frac{mg}{k} \right)e^{-\frac{kt}{m}}-\frac{mg}{k} \\
  s &= \frac{m}{k} \left( u+\frac{mg}{k} \right)
       \left( 1-e^{-\frac{kt}{m}} \right)-\frac{mgt}{k}
\end{align*}

At maximal height,

\begin{align*}
  v &= 0 \\
  t &= \frac{m}{k} \ln \left( 1+\frac{ku}{mg} \right) \\
  s &= \frac{mu}{k}-\frac{m^2 g}{k^2} \ln \left( 1+\frac{ku}{mg} \right) \\
    & \approx \frac{u^2}{2g}-\frac{ku^3}{3mg^2}+\frac{k^2u^4}{4m^2g^3}
\end{align*}

where $0<\dfrac{ku}{mg}<1$